# Doobie query to create a map

Tags: scala, doobie

Let's say I have some sql that is going to return a result set that looks like this:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | Val1 |
| A1 | Val2 |
| A1 | Val3 |
| B1 | Val4 |
| B1 | Val5 |
| B1 | Val6 |

```
val query = sql"""select blah""".query[(ID, VALUE)]
val result: ConnectionIO[(ID, List[VALUE])] = for {
  tuples <- query.to[List]
} yield tuples.traverse(t => t._1 -> t._2)
```

This is the closest I can get, but I get a compiler error:

```
Could not find an instance of Applicative for [+T2](ID, T2)
```

What I want is to turn this into a Map[ID, List[VALUE]]

Answer (score 0):

Here, `.traverse` isn't the most helpful method, try this instead:

```
val result: ConnectionIO[Map[ID, List[VALUE]]] = for {
  tuples <- query.to[List]
} yield tuples.groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
```

If you have Scala older than 2.13 you can try:

```
val result: ConnectionIO[Map[ID, List[VALUE]]] = for {
  tuples <- query.to[List]
} yield tuples
   .groupBy(_._1) // Map[ID, List[(ID, VALUE])]
   .mapValues(_.map(_._2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what DB you are using, but if you have arrays functions like postgresql you can try to use `group by` with `array_agg`. After you can just run `.asMap` or `.groupBy` on a `List[(ID, List[VALUE])]`.

```scala
val query = 
  sql"""select id, array_agg(value) as values group by id"""
    .query[(ID, List[VALUE])]
val result = query.to[List].map(_.toMap)
```